# Check prefiled formset and remove empty

Tags: django, django-forms

On my reservation site for an event, I want to allow people to manage their guests list. I represent the reservation with a `Registration` model and the guests with a `Guest` model using a foreign key `invited = models.ForeignKey(Registration)`.

I used a `modelformset_factory` to create a set of forms to record each guest at the registration. Now, to update this list, I use the following code:

```
registr = Registration.objects.get(id=postid) # get the registration
GuestFormSet = modelformset_factory(Guest,
                       extra=MAXGUESTS,
                       exclude=('invited',)) # generate MAXGUESTS Guest forms
guests = GuestFormSet(request.POST) # put the submited formset
if guests.is_valid():
    guests = guests.save(commit=False)
    for guest in guests:
        guest.invited = registr
        guest.save()
```

This works (+/-) to update the fields of an existing guest or to ass one but now I want to have the possibility to *delete* guest (simply by emptying the form of the guest). The problem is that I have an error "This field is required." for each field of the guest I want to remove.

Any idea how I can do that ?

Thank you

---

**Solution**

```
registr = Registration.objects.get(id=postid) # get the registration
maxg = max(0,MAXGUESTS - len(Guest.objects.filter(invited=registr))) # MAXGUEST form, existing guests included
GuestFormSet = modelformset_factory(Guest,
                       extra=maxg,
                       can_delete=True,
                       exclude=('invited',)) # generate MAXGUESTS Guest forms
guests = GuestFormSet(request.POST) # put the submited formset

if guests.is_valid():
    # create new guests
    guests = guests.save(commit=False)
    for guest in guests:
        guest.invited = registr
        guest.save()

    # get the guests from the updated database
    maxg = max(0,MAXGUESTS - len(Guest.objects.filter(invited=registr)))
    GuestFormSet = modelformset_factory(Guest, extra=maxg, can_delete=True, exclude=('invited',))
    guests = GuestFormSet(queryset=Guest.objects.filter(invited=registr))
```

Comment: I suggest checking how django.contrib.admin does it and do the same.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where does the admin interface does it. Could you give an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django I see that `modelformset_factory` accepts can_delete parameter: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py#L664

You can see can_delete mentioned here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Comment: Thank you, it works. I had some problems with extra fields created, when I add a guest, I put my updated code in the main message.